# Find series expansion of 1/cosx

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the series expansion of 1/cosx from basic series expansions.

I tried to find 1/cosx from the expansion of cosx but was unsure how to continue. When I found 1/cosx from the basic formula for finding series expansions I didn't get the same answer.

Answer (score 10):

$\sec\left(x\right)=\dfrac{1}{\cos \left(x\right)}$ is well-behaved about $x=0$, so assume 
$$
\frac{1}{\cos \left(x\right)} = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \ldots 
$$ 
Also, $\cos \left(x\right)$ is 
$$
\cos \left(x\right) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \ldots  
$$
So, on performing multiplication of the two series,
$$
1 \equiv a_0 + a_1 x +  \left(a_2 - \frac{1}{2!}\right)x^2 + \left(a_3 - \frac{a_1}{2}\right)x^3 + \left(a_4 - \frac{a_2}{2} + \frac{1}{24}\right)x^4 \ldots
$$
which, \left(on equating the coefficients on powers of x on the left and right hand sides\right) gives the first few terms as 
$a_0=1, a_1=0, a_2=\dfrac{1}{2}, a_3=0, a_4=\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{24} = \dfrac{5}{24}$. You can proceed to get more terms or a general formula for the nth term.

Answer (score 2):

(going to the fifth term for an example purpose)

Using the basic expansions of cos(x) gives us

$$
\frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24} + \cdots}
$$

of the form  $ \frac{1}{1-X} $ which has a known and easy expansion :
$$
1+X+X^2+X^3+X^4+X^5+\cdots
$$

where $ X = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} $ (approching $0$ when $x$ approaches $0$). The smaller $x$ term is $x^2$, so we don't need to take more terms than $X^2$ in the above expansion (otherwise terms would exceed $x^5$ and be negligeable).

Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{\cos(x)} = 1+(\frac{x^2}{2}−\frac{x^4}{24})+(\frac{x^2}{2})^2+o_{x\to0}(x^5)
$$

$$
= 1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\dfrac1{\cos x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!},~$ where $a_n$ form [this](http://oeis.org/A000364) sequence. See [Euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number) or [zigzag number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation#Related_integer_sequences) for

more details.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to derive it from basic series expansions like cosx?

Comment: @user183782: It's simply the [Taylor series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) of $\dfrac1{\cos x}$ for *x* around $0$.

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to figure out how to derive it from the 5 basic series expansions, without using the Taylor series formula or just plugging in 0 to the derivatives.

Comment: @user183782: Perhaps by writing $1=\cos^2x+\sin^2x$, and using the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) ?

Answer (score 0):

By the Euler formula
$$
\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i} x}=\cos x+\operatorname{i} \sin x,
$$
we find the relation
$$
\cos x=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i} x}+\operatorname{e}^{-\operatorname{i} x}}{2}.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\sec x&=\frac1{\cos x}\\
&=\frac{2}{\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i} x}+\operatorname{e}^{-\operatorname{i} x}}\\
&=\frac{2\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i} x}}{\operatorname{e}^{2\operatorname{i} x}+1}\\
&=\frac{2\operatorname{e}^{\frac12 (2\operatorname{i} x)}}{\operatorname{e}^{2\operatorname{i} x}+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n\biggl(\frac12\biggr)\frac{(2\operatorname{i}x)^n}{n!},
\end{align*}
where we used the generating function
\begin{equation}
\frac{2\operatorname{e}^{xt}}{\operatorname{e}^t+1}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}, \quad |t|<\pi
\end{equation}
of the Euler polynomials $E_n(x)$. Since the function $\sec x=\frac1{\cos x}$ is even, we derive
\begin{equation}
E_{2n+1}\biggl(\frac12\biggr)=0 \Longleftrightarrow E_{2n+1}=0,\quad n\ge0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
\sec x&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E_{2n}\biggl(\frac12\biggr)\frac{(2\operatorname{i}x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nE_{2n}\biggl(\frac12\biggr)\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{E_{2n}}{2^{2n}}\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nE_{2n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!},
\end{align}
where $E_{n}$ denotes the Euler numbers.

References

1. M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun (Eds), *Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables*, National Bureau of Standards, Applied Mathematics Series **55**, Reprint of the 1972 edition, Dover Publications, Inc., New York, 1992.
2. Xue-Yan Chen, Lan Wu, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Two identities and closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers in terms of central factorial numbers of the second kind*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 822--830; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0166.